# Need Help on A login Project (JAVA)

Tags: java

I have a button called `login` with an `if` and `else` somehow it still runs when the `if` is false instead of the `else` statement and also when I don't put any information in the `JTextField` and click on the `login button` it still runs, showing no errors

Here is the code:

```
        public static void main(String [] args){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("User Log In");
    frame.setSize(500,300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    //Labeling

    JLabel title = new JLabel("Please Log In");
    frame.add(title);
    JLabel user = new JLabel("UserName:");
    frame.add(user);
    JLabel pass = new JLabel("Password:");
    frame.add(pass);


      // Set the location on the frame

      title.setBounds(200, -25, 120, 145);
      user.setBounds(150,50,100,50);
      pass.setBounds(150,90,100,50);



      //Input Border

      JTextField userField = new JTextField();
      frame.add(userField);
      userField.setBounds(250,65,80,20);

      JPasswordField passField = new JPasswordField();
      frame.add(passField);

      passField.setBounds(250,105,80,20); 


      //Button

      JButton but1 = new JButton("LOGIN");
      frame.add(but1);
      but1.addActionListener(new Action());
      but1.setBounds(200,150,100,20);

}
      static class Action implements ActionListener{

          public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

            int password = 1234;

            if (password == 1234){


                    JFrame  frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setSize(500,300);
                    JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome To My Game");
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    frame.add(panel);
                    panel.add(label);     

                      }
                      else  {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Password Try Again");

                      }

          }


      }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int password = 1234;

if (password == 1234){
```

Because password is 1234, and that will always be true. Hence else never occurs.
You're not actually checking the user input.

Answer (score 0):

You intiallized the password to be 1234 as default, because that it always run.. change it

Comment: i change it but it gave me in error on the if statement  this  the error it gave me

Comment: The local variable password may not have been initialized